# Where's the Seraph Vendor in the Badass Crater of Badassitude?

Tags: borderlands-2

Apparently [Torgue's DLC has a Seraph Vendor](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Seraph_Vendor). That's news to me and I've completed the DLC's quests (and gotten seraph crystals). Apparently there's even [DLC 2 exclusive Seraph Weapons](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Boom_Blaster).

Where's the Seraph Vendor in the Badass Crater of Badassitude? Map screenshots and a general description of how to get there would be stellar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [Gearbox forums](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=213140):

> In the first area Mr. Torgue sends you before you meet Piston, right
>   on the way to the arena door. There's ammo/med vendors, the Seraph
>   door is nearby. Check the map for another $ icon.

Comment: Is it just me or is the embedded video showing up as a big blank for anyone?

Comment: @JeffMercado works for me

Comment: @BenBrocka: It's showing up for me now too. But earlier it just seemed like the youtube plugin on this video was not loading at all.

Comment: @BenBrocka Did you ever find it?